# Pyodbc cuting out trailing 0 from decimal(11,0)

Tags: python, hive, pyodbc

I'm querying HIVE database via `HORTONWORKS HIVE ODBC Driver` using `pyodbc '4.0.23'` in python 3.6. Table I'm querying contain field that is in `Decimal(11,0)` format. I have no control over upstream tasks that creates this table.

If the value of that field ends with 0 - for example `2112332230` the result from pyodbc execute will be `211233223` with last zero truncated.

**When using the same connector from other tools - like Power BI - I get correct result of `2112332230`.**

Here is the query:

```
select my_field from my_db.my_table
where my_field = 2112332230
```

and the result from `conn.execute(sql).fetchall()`:

```
[(Decimal('211233223'), )]
```

and the result for value that does not end with 0 - for example 2112332231:

```
[(Decimal('2112332231'), )]
```

Nothing got truncated.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is it a bug in pyodbc?

Comment: If you suspect that there might be a bug in pyodbc please create a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues) that includes a [mcve] and an [ODBC trace log](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Troubleshooting-%E2%80%93-Generating-an-ODBC-trace-log).

Comment: Unless someone will point some obvious mistake in my aproach thats exactly my plan

Comment: Well, I don't see anything particularly problematic in what you've shown us except perhaps that pyodbc 4.0.23 is a rather old version